# Pandas error 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
fe_split = pd.DataFrame(fe.Splitter_Name.str.split('SPL', 1).tolist(), columns=['splitter', 'number'])
```

`Splitter_Name` columns Data Example: `XYZSPL01, XYZSPL03`

Expected output: `splitter: XYZ, number:01`

This code used to work and now I'm getting the following error:

```
"AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns"
```

Any clues?

Comment: Can you share part of the data you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

u just need to check the shape of the data it should be (1,2) or (something ,1 ). For example, you can use the code below :

```
fe_split = pd.DataFrame([fe.Splitter_Name.str.split('SPL', 1).tolist()], columns=['splitter', 'number'])
```

I need more detail to help u more. Like the shape and type of the input data.